# Django as ORM - Perform update query asynchronously without blocking

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, orm

I'm using Djang as my ORM.
As part of my code I want to initiate an update request

```
some_object = SomeObject.objects.get(...)
calculated_value = func(some_object.value1, some_object.value2)
some_object.value1 = calulated_value
# This line should happen asynchrnoously and I don't if it fails
some_object.save()  # Can be replaced with some_object.update(value=calculated_value)

# continue doing other stuff
```

The `line some_object.save()` has some latency, but actually, I don't really mind if it fails, and I don't need its result. I want it to be handled by Django without the rest of the code waiting for it

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asynchronous task queue like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). It requires some set up but is valuable for performing scheduled background tasks.

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def set_calculated_value(object_id):
    some_object = SomeObject.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    calculated_value = func(some_object.value1, some_object.value2)
    some_object.value1 = calulated_value
    some_object.save()
```

Then you would call your task in a view/form/model method:

```
from .tasks import set_calculated_value

some_object = SomeObject.objects.get(...)
set_calculated_value.delay(instance.pk)
```